# Refreshing text in a TextBox at intervals of 1 second

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, timer, textbox

I am attempting to display the local time in a text box but have it refresh...   I used a timer to hopefully refresh the time, but it does not seem to reprint my text. If you could take the time to help me out that would be great!

EDIT*** So I attempted this with TextBox.AppendText() to see what happens if it continually reprints and I noticed that the date and time does not update at all. Do I need to refresh the form???

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim t As String = My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime
    Dim m As String = t & vbCrLf & " - Time Left - "
    Private Timer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Private TimerCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim TempText As String = m

    Protected Sub TimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        TextBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        TimerCounter += 1
        TextBox.Text = t
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown 'this goes with the line just above
        Timer = New Windows.Forms.Timer With {.Interval = 1000}
        AddHandler Timer.Tick, AddressOf TimerTick
        Timer.Start()
    End Sub

End Class
```

My expected result if for the local time to update in the `textbox1` each time the timer ticks.

Comment: Are you using `TimerCounter` somewhere? Set this: `TextBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center` in the Form's Designer. You don't need to re-set it at each `Timer.Tick`.

Comment: Very True on not having to reset the alignment. I didn't catch that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the variable *t* at the moment of its declaration, but then you never update it. So it contains always the same value.
In reality you don't even need that variable. You can set simply the TextBox.Text to the My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime

```
Protected Sub TimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' You can set this property just one time when you define your TextBox
    ' TextBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    TimerCounter += 1
    TextBox.Text = My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I just figured that out while I was waiting for a reply... I realize I don't need a variable and that I can just type it like that. I'm just being a lazy programmer for when i need to call it again later if need be.